# How does Rust parse ambiguous macros?

Tags: parsing, rust, macro

Rust's macros require them to be delimited by either parentheses, braces, or brackets, such as `println!(arg)` or `foo! { bar, baz }`. However, I have seen many examples of embedded scripting languages implemented via a macro. How does the Rust parser figure out where the macro ends? The language might have rogue braces or something in it, such as

```
python! {
    print("}")
}
```

While this can be solved by having the parser detect inner strings, what if my strings are delimited by `<` and `>`? Or what if my language does not require pairing brackets/braces, like many esolangs? Obviously pair matching cannot be used here, so how does Rust parse such macros?

Comment: Please see https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/macros.html `<` and `>` are not delimiters in Rust token trees.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The input to a Rust macro is a tree of Rust tokens and groups delimited by {}, (), or []. If your language does not conform to this structure, it cannot be parsed by a Rust macro.

Comment: Would it be fair to state that the "input" to a macro must be *lexically* valid Rust code?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I guess it would be one way to express it, though most people would likely not realize this doesn't mean _syntactically_ valid Rust code. I prefer to express it as _balanced token tree_, with emphasis on **balanced** here.

Comment: Lexically valid and with matching delimiters. Or at least the delimiter used to start the macro must be correctly matched. I'm not sure if you can have a boatload of unclosed `(` in a macro delimited by `{ }` or not, actually.